# Fortran : Limit in writing lenght in .dat

Tags: file-io, fortran, limit

My question is : Why Can I only write 102 lignes in a .dat but read more of them
I can generate 1 to 101 point, but anymore and it crash.
Here, the program in question and 3 examples of execution screen.

after some test, I wrote this :

this is my type cloud of point (containing number of point and each point coordinates)

> type ::point_
>
> ```
>    real :: x,y
> ```
>
> end type point_
>
> TYPE ::NuagePoints_
>
> ```
>    INTEGER :: m     ! nombre de points
>
>    type (point_), DIMENSION(1:degre_max+1) :: points      ! tableau des points
> ```
>
> END TYPE NuagePoints_

So Here is the test program I made :

module for_test_generate_nuage_points
    use NuagePoints_imp
    implicit none
    contains

```
subroutine mkNuageDePoints ()
implicit none
type (NuagePoints_) :: imported_cloud               !
integer             :: n,i                          !
real                :: pace,ordonnee,tampon,tampon2  !
logical             :: flag                         !
Write (*,*) "give first abscisse"
read (*,*) tampon
write (*,*) "give last abscisse"
read (*,*) tampon2
Write (*,*) "give the pace  (no more than 102 point)"
read (*,*) pace
n=nint((tampon2-tampon)/pace)+1
imported_cloud%m = n
!creation du nuage de point imported_cloud
do i=1,n
    imported_cloud%points(i)%x=tampon
                       !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ordonnee=tampon**2 !! Here write the function with "tampon" as variable !!
                       !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    imported_cloud%points(i)%y=ordonnee
    tampon=tampon+pace
end do
write (*,*) "the generated fonction right now is x^2"

!copy the  imported_cloud into abc.dat file
open (unit = 4, file = 'abc.dat', form='formatted')
    write (4,*) imported_cloud%m
do i=1,n
     write(4,*) imported_cloud%points(i)%x,imported_cloud%points(i)%y
end do
close (4)


write (*,*) "vdo you want to see the cloud generated ? (T)=yes; (F) = no"
read (*,*) flag
if (flag)then
    !open and read of file abc supposed to contain:
        !-in line 1 the number (m) of points 
        ! on following line, coordinates 
    open (unit = 4, file = 'abc.dat', form='formatted')
    read (4,*) n
    do i=1,n
        !write(*,*) imported_cloud%points(i)%x,imported_cloud%points(i)%y
        read(4,*) tampon,tampon2
        write (*,*) tampon,tampon2
    end do
     close (4)
end if
end subroutine mkNuageDePoints
```

## during execution 1 :

do you want to generate a cloud of point ? yes=(T) ; no = (F)

T

give first abscisse

0

give last abscisse

10

give the pace  (no more than 102 point)

1

the generated fonction right now is x^2

vdo you want to see the cloud generated ? (T)=yes; (F) = no

T

0.0000000       0.0000000

1.0000000       1.0000000

2.0000000       4.0000000

3.0000000       9.0000000

4.0000000       16.000000

5.0000000       25.000000

6.0000000       36.000000

7.0000000       49.000000

8.0000000       64.000000

9.0000000       81.000000

10.000000       100.00000

## during exection 2 :

do you want to generate a cloud of point ? yes=(T) ; no = (F)

T

give first abscisse

0

give last abscisse

101

give the pace  (no more than 102 point)

1

the generated fonction right now is x^2

vdo you want to see the cloud generated ? (T)=yes; (F) = no

T

0.0000000       0.0000000

1.0000000       1.0000000

2.0000000       4.0000000

3.0000000       9.0000000

4.0000000       16.000000

5.0000000       25.000000

```
       [...]
```

95.000000       9025.0000

96.000000       9216.0000

97.000000       9409.0000

98.000000       9604.0000

99.000000       9801.0000

100.00000       10000.000

101.00000       10201.000

## during execution 3

http://hpics.li/da26ea1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `degre_max` is only 100 so you touch out of bounds?

Compile with `-fbounds-check` (or something similar for your compiler) and/or use any [debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to find these kind of errors.

Comment: INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ordre_max = 1000




Sorry...

But I should also had write it, my bad